# How to do fillDown and fillRight using aspose dynamic formulas

Tags: excel, aspose-cells

I would like to use aspose dynamic formula to populate my excel sheets.

I have N X M rows for which i want to populate using my UDF formula.

i am using `&=&=MyUDFFunc(0{-1},1{0})~(horizontal, shift)`
which is able to write the cells horizontally.

I want same dynamic formula to fill Down also so that it will populate the entire table.
Is there any way we can do the same using aspose smartmarkers ?

Comment: When you do not use "horizontal" parameter in Smart Markers, by default, it will insert formulas/values vertically. So, one solution is you have to re-insert the smart markers formula (without using "horizontal" parameter) dynamically into the starting cell (in code) after you have processed smart markers and data is filled into cells horizontally.
PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: Thanks @AmjadSahi , Is it possible for you to share some example of that ?

Comment: I need to get your input file, current output file by Aspose.Cells and your expected output file, so I could evaluate it and devise you some sample code (if possible). Moreover, it is better if you could post your requirements/issue in Aspose.Cells forum (https://forum.aspose.com/c/cells/9), so we could assist you precisely.

Comment: Thanks @AmjadSahi. I have posted the query on the Aspose forum.